# updating state during animation breaks the animation

Tags: android, ios, react-native, animation, moti

I am using **moti** to have some animations, the points in the upper part circle does some animation and the text does fade in/out animation besides changing the text. doing the animation is fine with moti but when I update the text (settext("sth")) I think the whole screen rerenders and breaks the animation. how can I **update the text for each cycle** of the animation of moti ?

```
const ExerciseDetail = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const { colors } = useTheme();
  const { exercise } = route.params;
  bgBaseColor = exercise.bgcolor.slice(0, -4);

  // const [curveData, setCurveData] = React.useState([20, 10, 5, 10, 20])
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  // const [breathe, setBreate] = useState("Breathe In"); // true: Breathe In, false: Breathe Out
  myRef = useRef();


  // useEffect(() => {
  //   let intervalId;
  //   if (isPlaying) {
  //     intervalId = setInterval(() => {
  //       // texttttt = texttttt === "Breathe In" ? "Breathe Out" : "Breathe In";
  //       // textRef.current = textRef.current === "Hello" ? "Goodbye" : "Hello";
  //       // textRef.setNativeProps({ text: 'Value2' })
  //       // textRefcurrent.setNativeProps({ text: "initial value goes here" })
  //       // curveData[2] = curveData[2] === 5 ? 40 : 5;
  //       // setCurveData([...curveData]);
  //       console.log("Interval", myRef)
  //     }, exercise.duration);
  //   } else {
  //     clearInterval(intervalId);
  //   }
  //   return () => clearInterval(intervalId); // Cleanup function
  // }, [isPlaying]);

  const switchCurveData = () => {
    setIsPlaying(!isPlaying);
    // if(curveData[1] === 10){
    //   setCurveData([20,25,40,25,20])
    // }else{
    //   setCurveData([20,10,5,10,20])
    // }
  }


  return (
    <>
      <View style={{ ...styles.container, backgroundColor: colors.background }}>
        <HeaderBar leftIcon={'back'} title="Exercises" />
        <ScrollView
          contentContainerStyle={{
            // paddingBottom: 100,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}
        >
          <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 100, marginBottom: 100 }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
              <View style={[styles.dot, styles.center, {
                backgroundColor: exercise.bgcolor, shadowColor: "#fff",
                shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 }, shadowOpacity: 0.4, shadowRadius: 10,
              }]}>
                {[...Array(exercise.waveNum).keys()].map((index) => {
                  return (
                    <MotiView
                      from={{
                        opacity: 0.7,
                        scale: 1,
                      }}
                      animate={isPlaying ? {
                        opacity: 0,
                        scale: 4,
                      } : {
                        opacity: 0.7,
                        scale: 1,
                      }}
                      transition={isPlaying ?
                        {
                          type: 'timing',
                          duration: exercise.duration,
                          easing: Easing.out(Easing.ease),
                          delay: index * exercise.delayDuration,
                          repeatReverse: exercise.reverse, // stop moving bakwards
                          loop: true,
                        } : {}}
                      key={index}
                      style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject, styles.dot, { backgroundColor: exercise.bgcolor }]}

                    />
                  )
                })}

                <Image
                  source={exercise.icon}
                  style={{
                    height: 24,
                    width: 24,
                    borderRadius: 24,
                    tintColor: exercise.color,
                  }}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>


          <MotiView
            animate={{
              opacity: {
                value: isPlaying ? 1 : 0,
                onDidAnimate(finished, maybeValue, { attemptedValue }) {
                  if (maybeValue == 1) {
                  }else {
                  }
                  // console.log('[onDidAnimate] finished:', finished)
                  // console.log('[onDidAnimate] maybeValue:', maybeValue)
                  // console.log('[onDidAnimate] attemptedValue:', attemptedValue)
                },
              },
            }}
            exit={{
              alignContent: 'center',
              opacity: 1,
            }}
            transition={{
              loop: true,
              duration: exercise.duration,
              type: 'timing',
            }}
            style={styles.shape}
          >
            <Text style={{ color: COLORS.white }}></Text>
          </MotiView>

          {/* <Animated.View style={{ opacity: fadeAnim }}>
            <Text style={{ color: COLORS.white }}>{myRef.current.transition.maybeValue ==1 ? "Breathe Out" : "Breathe In"}</Text>
          </Animated.View> */}

          <Text style={{ ...FONTS.h5, color: COLORS.white, textAlign: 'center' }}>{exercise.time}</Text>
          <Text style={{ ...FONTS.fontSm, color: COLORS.white, textAlign: 'center' }}>{exercise.level}</Text>
          <Text style={{ ...FONTS.h3, color: colors.text, textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: 20 }}>{exercise.title}</Text>
          <Text style={{ ...FONTS.h6, color: colors.text, textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: 20 }}>{exercise.description}</Text>
          <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 5, width: '50%' }}>
            <CustomButton color={bgBaseColor + ".6)"} title='Start' onPress={() => switchCurveData()} />
          </View>

          {/* <View style={{width:SIZES.width,alignItems:'flex-start',paddingTop:35}}>
                <VictoryChart 
                height={120}
                padding={0}>
                <Defs>
                    <LinearGradient x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%" id="gradientStroke" >
                    <Stop offset="0%" stopOpacity={.4} stopColor={exercise.color}/>
                    <Stop offset="70%" stopOpacity={0} stopColor={exercise.color}/>
                    <Stop offset="100%" stopOpacity={0} stopColor={exercise.color}/>
                    </LinearGradient>
                </Defs>
                <VictoryArea
                    domain={{y : [0,80]}}
                    interpolation="natural"
                    animate={{
                    duration: 1000,
                    onLoad: { duration: 1000 }
                    }}
                    style={{
                    data: {
                        fill: 'url(#gradientStroke)', fillOpacity: 0.6, stroke: exercise.color, strokeWidth: 2
                    },
                    labels: {
                        fontSize: 15,
                        fill: ({ datum }) => datum.x === 3 ? "#000000" : "#c43a31"
                    },
                    
                    }}
                    data={curveData}
                    labels={({ datum }) => datum.x}
                />
                </VictoryChart>
            </View> */}

        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </>
  )
}
```

[image]